# /home/steam/.steam/steam.sh: not found

Tags: steam

I am trying to run an Arma 3 dedicated server, but at startup it says steam.sh is missing. I've done an apt purge and removal of the `.steam` directory, reran steamcmd, and it's still missing. I've also reinstalled Arma 3 dedicated server and still get the same error.

```
~/arma3$ /home/steam/arma3/arma3master/arma3server -name=server1 -profiles=/home/steam/arma3/arma3profiles
0:39:34 No product.bin found, using defaults for a core engine.
sh: 1: /home/steam/.steam/steam.sh: not found
 0:39:34 Unable to locate a running instance of Steam. Restarting...
ErrorMessage: Unable to locate a running instance of Steam
Application terminated intentionally
 0:39:34 ../lib/Network/networkServer.cpp ClearNetServer:NOT IMPLEMENTED - briefing!
Unable to locate a running instance of Steam
 0:39:34 Extensions:
```

Here's what appears when I do a `ls` of the `.steam` directory

```
~/.steam$ ls
SteamApps  appcache  config  logs  registry.vdf  root  ssfn6918091982445337148  steam  steam.pid  steam.pipe  steamcmd  ubuntu12_32  userdata
```

I also just tried running steam on its on and it wouldn't start up. Not sure if related.

```
~$ steam
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[2019-06-30 00:41:25] Startup - updater built Nov 23 2016 01:05:42
../steamexe/updateui_xwin.cpp (339) : Assertion Failed: Could not open connection to X
../steamexe/main.cpp (525) : Assertion Failed: failed to initialize update status ui, or create initial window
sh: 1: /home/steam/.steam/steam_msg.sh: not found
```

My Ubuntu version info:

**Distributor ID:** Ubuntu
**Description:**    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
**Release:**        18.04
**Codename:**       bionic

Comment: Is the arma server run through a dedicated app user? If so, the home directory might be under `/home/armauser` instead of `/home/youruser`. Also ensure you aren't trying to run Steam as root, as it will flat out refuse to do so.

Comment: Everything is ran through the user `steam`. I am not running anything as root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to not being inside the Arma 3 Dedicated Server folder, where arma3master is located. Despite running the executable with the absolute path, you still need to be within the folder that the executable is in.

The solution was to change directory to the executable folder.

```
$ cd /home/steam/arma3/arma3master/
$ /home/steam/arma3/arma3master/arma3server -name=server1 -profiles=/home/steam/arma3/arma3profiles
15:12:31 SteamAPI initialization failed. Steam features won't be accessible!
15:12:31 Initializing stats manager.
15:12:31 Stats config disabled.
15:12:31 sessionID: 48e7e271bbb26c6d5aea043682c0101f9e0b6f61
15:12:37 Updating base class RscShortcutButton->RscButton, by a3\editor_f\config.bin/RscDisplayEditObject/Controls/B_OK/ (original bin\config.bin)
# ...
```

Comment: Those can be rough to figure out. Usually means a script uses relative paths rather than absolute. Good work figuring it out.